# Dynamically creation of segmented-button in Sencha-touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

Hello I am refactoring a class in Sencha Touch, my proposal is creating dynamically segmented button in a toolbar. In the parent class I am implementing this solution:

```
{
    xtype     : 'segmentedbutton',
    cls       : 'filterbar-customer-segmented-button',
    itemId    : 'surveyFilterCustomerSegmentedButton',
    pressedCls: 'filterbar-segmented-button-pressed',
    items: []
}
```

In two different controllers I am using this to create items inside of the segmented-button:

```
createSegmentedFilters: function (store){
    var segmentedFilterCustomer = this.getSegmentedButton();
    segmentedFilterCustomer.setItems([
      {
        text    : Survey.util.I18n.getLabelWithArgs('CustomerHeaderAll', store.getCount()),
        itemId  : 'showAllCustomers',
        iconCls : 'user',
        iconMask: true,
        pressed : true
      },
      {
        text    : Survey.util.I18n.getLabelWithArgs('CustomerHeaderWithSurvey', this.filterWithSurveys(store)),
        itemId  : 'showCustomersWithSurvey',
        iconCls : 'compose',
        iconMask: true
      }
    ]);
  },
```

and when I load the view call to the method `createSegmentedFilters` but I am having a curious behaviour only I can load once the segmentedbutton, it is like the component is working in one way..

In my home-view I have two buttons with two different options, calling to two different views and controllers, toolbar is the same except the number of items inside the component segmented-button, for this weird reason is happening?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please excuse me, I'm having a little trouble comprehending the question. Could you please rephrase the question? I just want to know what is expected and what is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Ok Sorry.. I expected different items for each segmented button depending on the view..

Comment: No worries. Please do correct me if I'm wrong; however, `this.getSegmentedButton()` is going to get the same segmented button object in all the controllers, isn't it? As you're setting items on the same object every time, you'll get the last set items in UI for all the views.

Comment: Yes, exactly... how to solve this?

Comment: You need to have 2 different instances of segmented buttons.